# Align moderncv header

Tags: moderncv, letters

With the default style, the recipient and my address info is vertically shifted against each other, resulting in a huge blank space above the recipients field.

Is there a way to either align my address and the recipient or to move the recipient upwards? Since it's a cover letter it does not need to fit a window envelop like `scrlttr2` can do.

I'm using `\moderncvstyle{classic}`

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=10pt]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale = 0.75]{geometry}

% Schriftart
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}                 % Helvetica (skaliert) als serifenlose Schriftart (Standard fuer serifenlose Schrift)  -- besser geeigent zum Lesen am BILDSCHIRM
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       % (Eingestellte) serifenlose Schrift als Standardschrftart (fuer Fliesstext)
%\usepackage{lmodern}                           % Besser lesbare Standardschriftart (Serifenschrift) -- besser geeigent zum Lesen auf PAPIER
%   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}       % (Eingestellte) Serifenschriftart als Standardschrift (fuer Fliesstext)
%\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}   % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (fett)
%\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}            % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (plain)
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % Textfarbe aendern - Fuer Dokument, Paragraph oder diskrete Texteile mit '\textcolor{Farbe}{Text}'

%------------------------------------------------------------

% Ausgabe von Umlauten (vor 'inputenc' einbinden!)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Schoene Ausgabe von Umlauten
%------------------------------------------------------------


% Deutsche Eingabe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Umlaute direkt eingeben   UTF-8 zur besseren Zusammenarbeit mit vers. Betriebssystemen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Eingabe (Zur Eingabe von Umlauten wird 'inputenc' benötigt)
%------------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tweaklist}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{blindtext}



%--------------- EINSTELLUNGEN LEBENSLAUF ------------------
\moderncvstyle{classic} % Optionen: casual, classic, oldstyle, banking
\moderncvcolor{ihkblue} 

% Blocksatz im Anschreiben
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
{\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
{\@opening}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------- ANSCHREIBEN ----------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------- ANGABEN ------------------------

\firstname{My}
\familyname{Name}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Street}{12345 City}{Cuntry}
\mobile{+00 (0)123 456 7890}
\phone{+00 (0)123 456 7890}
\email{myname@adress.com}
%\photo[120pt][0.4pt]{/some/path/to/a/foto.jpg}


\begin{document}

\recipient{Company}{
        %   \\% 3. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        %   \\% 2. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        %   \\% 1. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        Big Corp.   \\% 1. AZ   Firma   Beispiel AG
        Mr. \\% 2. AZ   Anrede  Herr/Frau ggf. Berufs- oder Amtsbezeichnungen
        Jon Doe \\% 3. AZ   ggf. Akademische Grade, Name
        Streetdrive 1   \\% 4. AZ   Straße Hausnummer (ggf. //App.-Nr.) oder Postfach
        12345 Cityville \\% 5. AZ   Postleitzahl und Bestimmungsort
        %   \\% 6. AZ   LAND (wenn außerhalb des Absenderlandes und dann in GROSSBUCHSTABEN im eigennamen der Landessprache)
    }
\date{\today}
\opening{\textbf{Subject bla bla} \\[10pt]
         Dear Mr. Doe, }

\closing{Kind regards}

\makelettertitle

    \blindtext \blindtext

\makeletterclosing
\newpage
```

After that, there's just the CV, which works just fine.

[image: That's not a nice recipient box]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can change command `\makeletterhead` to use two minipages beneath each other for the recipient (first one) and the personal data (second one). I included your `\patchcmd` to the new definition of `\makeletterhead`.

With the following MWE

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=10pt]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale = 0.75]{geometry}

% Schriftart
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}                 % Helvetica (skaliert) als serifenlose Schriftart (Standard fuer serifenlose Schrift)  -- besser geeigent zum Lesen am BILDSCHIRM
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       % (Eingestellte) serifenlose Schrift als Standardschrftart (fuer Fliesstext)
%\usepackage{lmodern}                           % Besser lesbare Standardschriftart (Serifenschrift) -- besser geeigent zum Lesen auf PAPIER
%   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}       % (Eingestellte) Serifenschriftart als Standardschrift (fuer Fliesstext)
%\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}   % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (fett)
%\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}            % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (plain)
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % Textfarbe aendern - Fuer Dokument, Paragraph oder diskrete Texteile mit '\textcolor{Farbe}{Text}'

%------------------------------------------------------------

% Ausgabe von Umlauten (vor 'inputenc' einbinden!)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Schoene Ausgabe von Umlauten
%------------------------------------------------------------


% Deutsche Eingabe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Umlaute direkt eingeben   UTF-8 zur besseren Zusammenarbeit mit vers. Betriebssystemen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Eingabe (Zur Eingabe von Umlauten wird 'inputenc' benötigt)
%------------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tweaklist}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{blindtext}



%--------------- EINSTELLUNGEN LEBENSLAUF ------------------
\moderncvstyle{classic} % Optionen: casual, classic, oldstyle, banking
\moderncvcolor{blue} % ihkblue

% Blocksatz im Anschreiben
\makeatletter
\renewcommand*{\makeletterhead}{%
  % recompute lengths (in case we are switching from letter to resume, or vice versa)
  \recomputeletterlengths%
    % recipient block
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth} % <================================
    \raggedright%
    \addressfont%
    {\bfseries\upshape\@recipientname}\\%
    \@recipientaddress%
  \end{minipage}
  % sender contact info
  \hfill%
  \begin{minipage}[t]{.49\textwidth}% <=================================
    % optional detailed information
    \if@details%
      \raggedleft%
      \addressfont\textcolor{color2}{%
        {\bfseries\upshape\@firstname~\@lastname}\@firstdetailselementfalse%
        % optional detailed information
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@addressstreet}}{}{\makenewline\addresssymbol\@addressstreet%
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscity}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscity}% if \addresstreet is defined, \addresscity and addresscountry will always be defined but could be empty
          \ifthenelse{\equal{\@addresscountry}{}}{}{\makenewline\@addresscountry}}%
        \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
          \makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@email}}{}{\makenewline\emailsymbol\emaillink{\@email}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@homepage}}{}{\makenewline\homepagesymbol\httplink{\@homepage}}%
        \ifthenelse{\isundefined{\@extrainfo}}{}{\makenewline\@extrainfo}}\fi%
      \\[1em] % <=======================================================
      \@date % <========================================================
    \end{minipage}\\[2em] 
  % opening
% \raggedright% <=======================================================
  \@opening\\[1.5em]%
  % ensure no extra spacing after \makelettertitle due to a possible blank line
%  \ignorespacesafterend% not working
  \hspace{0pt}\par\vspace{-\baselineskip}\vspace{-\parskip}}
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------- ANSCHREIBEN ----------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------- ANGABEN ------------------------

\firstname{My}
\familyname{Name}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Street}{12345 City}{Cuntry}
\mobile{+00 (0)123 456 7890}
\phone{+00 (0)123 456 7890}
\email{myname@adress.com}
%\photo[120pt][0.4pt]{/some/path/to/a/foto.jpg}


\begin{document}

\recipient{Company}{
        %   \\% 3. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        %   \\% 2. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        %   \\% 1. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        Big Corp.   \\% 1. AZ   Firma   Beispiel AG
        Mr. \\% 2. AZ   Anrede  Herr/Frau ggf. Berufs- oder Amtsbezeichnungen
        Jon Doe \\% 3. AZ   ggf. Akademische Grade, Name
        Streetdrive 1   \\% 4. AZ   Straße Hausnummer (ggf. //App.-Nr.) oder Postfach
        12345 Cityville \\% 5. AZ   Postleitzahl und Bestimmungsort
        %   \\% 6. AZ   LAND (wenn außerhalb des Absenderlandes und dann in GROSSBUCHSTABEN im eigennamen der Landessprache)
    }
\date{\today}
\opening{\textbf{Subject bla bla} \\[10pt]
         Dear Mr. Doe, }

\closing{Kind regards}

\makelettertitle

    \blindtext \blindtext

\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```

you get the result:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

A simple fix with a vspace:

```
\documentclass[a4paper, fontsize=10pt]{moderncv}
\usepackage[scale = 0.75]{geometry}

% Schriftart
\usepackage[scaled=.92]{helvet}                 % Helvetica (skaliert) als serifenlose Schriftart (Standard fuer serifenlose Schrift)  -- besser geeigent zum Lesen am BILDSCHIRM
    \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\sfdefault}       % (Eingestellte) serifenlose Schrift als Standardschrftart (fuer Fliesstext)
%\usepackage{lmodern}                           % Besser lesbare Standardschriftart (Serifenschrift) -- besser geeigent zum Lesen auf PAPIER
%   \renewcommand{\familydefault}{\rmdefault}       % (Eingestellte) Serifenschriftart als Standardschrift (fuer Fliesstext)
%\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily\bfseries}   % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (fett)
%\setkomafont{sectioning}{\rmfamily}            % Ueberschriften in Serifenschrift (plain)
\usepackage{xcolor}                             % Textfarbe aendern - Fuer Dokument, Paragraph oder diskrete Texteile mit '\textcolor{Farbe}{Text}'

%------------------------------------------------------------

% Ausgabe von Umlauten (vor 'inputenc' einbinden!)
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}        % Schoene Ausgabe von Umlauten
%------------------------------------------------------------


% Deutsche Eingabe
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}     % Umlaute direkt eingeben   UTF-8 zur besseren Zusammenarbeit mit vers. Betriebssystemen
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}     % deutsche Eingabe (Zur Eingabe von Umlauten wird 'inputenc' benötigt)
%------------------------------------------------------------


\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{tweaklist}
\usepackage{calc}
\usepackage{xparse}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage{tikz}


\usepackage{blindtext}



%--------------- EINSTELLUNGEN LEBENSLAUF ------------------
\moderncvstyle{classic} % Optionen: casual, classic, oldstyle, banking
%\moderncvcolor{ihkblue} 

% Blocksatz im Anschreiben
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\makeletterhead}% <cmd>
{\raggedright \@opening}% <search>
{\@opening}% <replace>
{}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother
%------------------------------------------------------------



%------------------------------------------------------------
%------------------------- ANSCHREIBEN ----------------------
%------------------------------------------------------------

% -------------------------- ANGABEN ------------------------

\firstname{My}
\familyname{Name}
\title{Lebenslauf}
\address{Street}{12345 City}{Cuntry}
\mobile{+00 (0)123 456 7890}
\phone{+00 (0)123 456 7890}
\email{myname@adress.com}
%\photo[120pt][0.4pt]{/some/path/to/a/foto.jpg}

\let\oldrecipient\recipient
\def\recipient#1#2{\oldrecipient{\vspace{-100pt}#1}{#2}}

\recipient{Company}{
        %   \\% 3. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        %   \\% 2. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        %   \\% 1. ZVZ  Postalische Zusätze und Vermerke (Max. 3 Zeilen)
        Big Corp.   \\% 1. AZ   Firma   Beispiel AG
        Mr. \\% 2. AZ   Anrede  Herr/Frau ggf. Berufs- oder Amtsbezeichnungen
        Jon Doe \\% 3. AZ   ggf. Akademische Grade, Name
        Streetdrive 1   \\% 4. AZ   Straße Hausnummer (ggf. //App.-Nr.) oder Postfach
        12345 Cityville \\% 5. AZ   Postleitzahl und Bestimmungsort
        %   \\% 6. AZ   LAND (wenn außerhalb des Absenderlandes und dann in GROSSBUCHSTABEN im eigennamen der Landessprache)
    }
\date{\today}

\begin{document}

\opening{\textbf{Subject bla bla} \\[10pt]
         Dear Mr. Doe, }

\closing{Kind regards}

\makelettertitle

    \blindtext \blindtext

\makeletterclosing
\end{document}
```

Just redefined the command with the problem to include a `\vspace` manually selected.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can get around without using [`moderncv`](//ctan.org/pkg/moderncv)'s lettering capabilities:

[image]

```
\documentclass[10pt]{article}

\usepackage{lipsum,xcolor,fontawesome}

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Remove paragraph indent
\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}

{\slshape \begin{tabular}[t]{ @{} l }
  \upshape\bfseries Company \\
  Big Corp.     \\
  Mr.           \\
  Jon Doe       \\
  Streetdrive 1 \\
  12345 Cityville
\end{tabular}}\hfill
{\color{black!80}\slshape\small \begin{tabular}[t]{ r @{} }
  \upshape\bfseries My Name \\
  Street \\
  12345 City \\
  Country \\
  \textup{\faPhone} +00 (0) 123 456 7890 \\
  \textup{\faMobile} +00 (0) 123 456 7890 \\
  \textup{\faEnvelopeO} myname@address.com
\end{tabular}}

\medskip

\hfill\today

\bigskip

\textbf{Subject bla bla}

\medskip

Dear Mr.\ Doe,

\medskip

\lipsum

\bigskip

Kind regards,

\medskip

Me

\end{document}
```

Use `[t]`op-aligned `tabular`s for the sender/recipient contact details.

I find the code far more legible and matching with the output, and therefore prefer this approach than to use the built-in document class style.